# Skill points in dragon age origins

Tags: dragon-age-origins

How many skill points do I receive (as a mage) during the game?

I definitely want full coercion, but I would also like Herbalism and maybe combat training. Is herbalism worth it, or should I simply ignore it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You start with three skill points (one given by class, one by origin, and one that's "free").

Mages and warriors gain additional skill points every third level starting at level 3 (so: 3, 6, 9, etc). Rogues gain additional points every second level.

The level cap of the original game is 25, so that provides 8 additional skill points to mages (at level 24). However, you should expect to only be level 20-22 from completing the core game and all side quests, you'll need the available DLC to get to the cap.

This means that, as a mage, **you should probably expect a total of 10 skills points from the core game** by reaching level 21, and maybe 11 if you have DLC and can reach level 24.

Note that the Awakening expansion increases the level cap to 35, providing the potential for an additional 3 skill points to Mages.

*For an additional source check the [XP Table](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Level#Experience_Table) on the Dragon Age Wikia.*

---

As for which skills to obtain, Coercion is a good choice, for obvious reasons, but I personally off-loaded most "crafting" skills to other party members saving my main character's skill points for combat training, tactics and survival - but then I was a rogue so had more points to play with anyway...

Comment: +1 for using other characters to craft, some of them start out with points in it anyway, and you only need one character with the skill.

Comment: Who should I use for herbalism?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be whoever you like. The skill has no effect except for allowing the character to craft. As bwarner says, some characters start with points in these skills already (in fact, every Mage starts with it at level 1, if I remember correctly?), so it's probably easiest just to take one of those characters, and go from there. IIRC, I gave most party characters one of the crafting skills (and the main character coercion instead), that way all bases were covered across the party.

Answer (score 0):

Coercion is a great investment, thumbs up.

Combat training is optional, best for primal mages and shape changers, so that it will be harder for your spells to be interrupted. Spirit and creation don't rely heavily upon it. Entropy is basically touchy feely spells that make your mage battle ready, but do not rely on combat training. Therefore, thumbs down.

Herbalism is sort of useful during ostagar and origin stories, but I recommend just the basic one, so as not to overdo it, because Morrigan shows up with improved herbalism and seriously, you only need one. Thumbs up though.

I think that you should concentrate more on stealing. That gives you really nice stuff! It can work for you any time except the final battle. (Thumbs up for that, you can't count on Leliana because she is a total weakling she is only useful in your tent and in lothering.)

Combat tactics would also receive a thumbs up.